# Override property on IEnumerable object

Tags: c#

I have this object:

```
var child = Mapper.Map<List<ChildViewModel>>( model.ChildData );
```

and I return this:

```
return new OutputViewModel
  {
      ChildData = child
  };
```

But In the middle I need to perform a change in one of the child property, I tried this:

```
var dummy = child.Select(e => e.Number = FormatNumber(e.Number, e.Mask));
```

so when I return OutputViewModel the job is done, I have my Number property formatted, is there a better way to do it because I don't like it :(

Comment: Do you have to do the formatting in middle of adding items to list? Cant you format your number at the end? If you can, I can tell you how to change some of your items using Linq.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not make a read-only property that has the number formatted?

```
public class OutputViewModel
{
    public decimal Number { get; set; }
    public object Mask { get; set; }
    public string NumberFormatted 
    {
        get { return FormatNumber(Number, Mask); }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

LINQ is for querying, not for modifying the collection. You can see the change in your collection because of *somewhat* side effect due to reference passed to the lambda expression.

A better way would be to use a simple iteration, modify the property of object in each iteration and then return the collection, that will convey the intent in a better way, IMO.